# For debugging can I set my java application run in a different timezone to the local machine?

Tags: java, angular, timezone

I am trying to debug a stubborn problem related to timezones, with a java backend and angular frontend. I am running both apps locally and it would be useful if I could have them in different timezones from each other. I was hoping to find a way of starting up the Java application in a timezone different from the local machine (and therefore different from the browser/angular application). Any ideas?

Comment: What problem is it exactly? Can you describe it and provide some example code?

Comment: Sure, you can pass the time zone as a command line option, e.g. like described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/troubleshoot/time-zone-settings-jre.htm#JSTGD376 or here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-jvm-time-zone

Comment: Thanks that looks like it will work for me. The bug is when the end user (browser) is in a different timezone to the server (java app) and you choose a date on a date picker, its selecting the day before. Once I can replicate the test scenario I have a chance of fixing it.